# How do I add a RSS feed for a custom search on a website?

Tags: search, rss

I would like to setup an RSS feed for the results returned by [this search](http://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/offres/provence_alpes_cote_d_azur/alpes_maritimes/?f=a&th=1&mrs=1600&mre=999999&sqs=9&sqe=11&ros=3&ret=1&ret=4). The website in question does not appear to offer RSS, but is there a tool that generate an RSS feed for a search?

Comment: I have the same question, did you find a solution?

Comment: if this is off topics then where should it be asked?

Answer (score 1):

Google reader can do this for you.  Although it doesn't actually create an rss feed, it does feature the same functionality, as long as you read your feeds through google reader.

Comment: google reader is dead...

Comment: @user4050 true, a great loss..

Comment: so what's a new solution?

Comment: For this specific website in the question, there is now a 'Créez une alerte' ("Create an alert") button, which probably (?) allows you to receive updates by email. I don't know any applications that can do this for you, though :(